# Error: Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument (SDK PHP FACEBOOK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to follow the example: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk but when i run in browser: http://192.168.33.10/fb_api/firstapp.php/, error: *Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument*. I checked app_id and app_scret.
My source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$access_token = 'EAACEdEose0cBABaxt3VjDmUiG8H5DQ8Dhju....';
$app_secret = '98680d3e6a251b52d87d...';
$appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);
require "phpsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    "app_id" => '11651982...',
    "app_secret" => '98680d3e6a251b52d87...',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);
try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
    // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    $response = $fb->get('/me', 'EAACEdEose0cBABaxt3VjDmUiG8H5DQ8DhjuZB12Phbyc2ZB0G....');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if the SDK calculates that on its own, when you provide an access token yourself. You should not work with fixed user(?) access tokens stored in code; implement FB login to get a fresh user token. And when you create variables to hold stuff such as access tokens, app ids etc., then you should perhaps actually use those variables in the following code, instead of repeating the same values again.

Comment: @CBroe I created file login.php and callback.php follow the example: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/docs/examples/facebook_login.md. Why i can't get AccessToken??  Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500 Internal Server Error is - you go check the server’s log files to find out what the actual error was.

Comment: Why my project run on your computer, it still great and get access token success. But my computer can't get access token.